# Calculated Column IF OR AND Formula not Working

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated field with the following formula, but when I try to save the column with this formula it returns a syntax error.

What's wrong with the formula?

Formula:

```
= IF(
  OR(
    AND([daysinadvance] >= 14, [totaldays] >= 1), 
    AND([daysinadvance] < 14, [totaldays] < 7)
  ), 
  "Pass", 
  "Fail"
)
```

Basically if somebody take a leave more than 14 days in advance he is allowed to take anything more than 1 day or if somebody take a leave less than 14 days in advance he is allowed to take anything less than 7 days.

Comment: What are your column types for [daysinadvance],[totaldays] and your calculated column? I have created these columns in a SharePoint list as number columns and your formula works fine.

Comment: Your formula syntax looks fine. Check if you are having correct data types for your columns. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula, in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`). Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Thank you! Your assumption was correct. I have changed the formula to the local format and it works! My actual formula is in Russian and looks like:
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И([daysinadvance]>=14; [totaldayss]>=1); И([daysinadvance]<14; [totaldayss]<7)); "Pass"; "Fail")

Comment: @user79408 Thank you for your time to clarify my doubts! I have changed the formula to the local format and it works! My actual formula is in Russian and looks like: =ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И([daysinadvance]>=14; [totaldayss]>=1); И([daysinadvance]<14; [totaldayss]<7)); "Pass"; "Fail")

Comment: I have added the answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula syntax looks fine to me. Try below suggestion:

Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in calculated column formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Documentation**: [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))